# Convert Cents to Euro

Tags: python, python-3.x

i'm relatively new to Phyton programming so excuse me if this question seems dumb but i just cant find an Answer for it.

How do i convert a number like lets say 1337 to 13,37€

All I have for now is this Code Sample:

```
number = 1337

def price():
    Euro = 0
    if number >= 100
        Euro = Euro + 1
```

But obviously i need to put this in some kind of for-loop, kinda like this:

```
number = 1337

def price():
    Euro = 0
    for 100 in number:
        Euro = Euro + 1
```

But this doesn't seem to work for me.

EDIT:

Also, how do i convert that number correctly if i just divide by 100 i get 13.37 but what i want is 13,37€.

Comment: How about just `number / 100.0`?

Comment: @michaelrccurtis but i cant divide for example 7 through 100.

Comment: @Lyux What are you talking about? You definitely can...

Comment: @Lyux: just type `7 / 100` into your interactive prompt ;)

Comment: @ozgur Also, how do  i convert the number into a currency?

Comment: @Lyux what do you mean by currency? converting 1 cent into into a euro? You need to know how much 1 dollar is in euros.

Comment: @ozgur i mean i get what the other guys told me, so i now have 13,37 but how do i convert this into 13,37€

Comment: @Lyux: Python does not support currency symbols in numbers; because `13.37` is a decimal number, while `"13.37€"` must be a string you need to convert it: e.g. `str(13.37) + "€"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because Python does not support any currency symbols in numbers, you need to convert a number to a string and append the currency (`"€"`) character to it: `str(13.37) + "€"`:

```
def convertToCent(number):
    return '{:,.2f}€'.format(number/100)
```

---

As @ozgur and @chepner pointed out the so called "true division" of two integers is only possible in Python 3:

> `x / y` returns a reasonable approximation of the mathematical result of the division ("true division")

Python 2 only returns the actual floating-point quotient when one of the operands are floats.

> The future division statement, spelled "`from __future__ import division`", will change the / operator to mean true division throughout the module.

*For more information see [PEP 238](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/).*

Comment: upvoted since OP uses Python3.x, however, one should note that it doesn't work on Python2.x.

Comment: @ozgur: Yes you are completely right! Thanks I will add it :)

Comment: This works best for my case, thanks for helping everybody.

Comment: The only thing you need to make it work in Python 2.7 is to divide by 100.0 to ensure floating-point division. (Or use `from __future__ import division`.)

Answer (score -2):

This shouldn't be hard to guess:

```
number = 1337

def price(number):
    return (euro / 100.0)

print prince(number)
```